# How to print output in single line in linux terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code:

```html
data2 = [["jsdfgweykdfgwey",
          "kdgwehogfdoyeo",
          "ndlgyehwfgdiye",
          "ndfluiwgmdfho"],
          ["---------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
           "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
           "------------------------------------------------------------------------------",
           "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------"],
          ["kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt1",
           "kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt2",
           "kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt3",
           "kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt4\
kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt4 \
kdglwduifgeuifeudiwfkjkedluefywduifkcjkewfgpt4"]]

data = [x for x in data2 if x is not None]
col_width = max(len(word) for row in data for word in row) + 2
for row in data:
    print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)#print in single line in output console.
```

It is not printing output properly

How to print output in single line in command output (OS Linux)

or any other suggestions to print in column wise for long line printing.

Comment: Can you show what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: what should the output look like? print everything in data2?
`print "".join([item for items in data2 for item in items])`

Comment: Because of long line printing, console output showing   printing in new lines. its confusing to read out output. so I am reducing output print for each line

Answer (score 0):

Each element in your list is printed out as a combined string as you wished. But by doing the `word.ljust(col_width)` step, where col_width is about 140, you are taking up a lot of empty space for printing. If your console size is small it will seem like you are printing in a new line. Try to replace col_width by 10, you will probably get the elements of data2[0] printed in one line.

If you want data2 to be printed as a single string then you can do the following:

```
tmp=''
for row in data:
    a = " ".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)
    tmp = tmp + a
```

`tmp` will contain each element of data2 in a string one after the other